# how to find a variable definition in PHP project

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

Currently I am working on a large php project and using xampp server and brackets IDE. Can anyone please tell me how to find the specific line or file where the variable is first defined.

Comment: `ctrl+f` then type variable name.

Comment: try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970806/find-where-a-variable-is-defined-in-php-and-or-smarty) or if you are trying to do it from code and know the physical site of origin you can do `$origin = __LINE__;` to get the line number.

Comment: grep -Rn '${variable_name/pattern}' * | less

Comment: thanks for the reply but variable defined in a separate file so i cant use find option

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3rd party applications like **[Actual Search and Replace](http://www.divlocsoft.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can find the variable definition across files in brackets..

Shift+ctrl+F on windows.

You can also manually navigate to the option via 
the menu bar

Find > Find in Files

It will give you instances of the search string across all files in the project.