# Find where variable is defined in PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I know that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970806/find-where-a-variable-is-defined-in-php-and-or-smarty), but that doesn't help me in any way even though I have the same problem of being a big project and not being able to find where a variable is first defined.

**What I've tried:**
I tried the find function from phpstorm (cmd+shift+f) and searched all files of the project, to no avail. The variable is `$_SESSION['some_index']` it is used in multiple places in the code, but I could only find one place where it is assigned:

`$_SESSION['some_index'] = someclass->getVar()`

so I tried going there, that class has no constructor and the `setVar()` function is only called once, and is passed (ironically) `$_SESSION['some_index']`.

If there any way to follow the code maybe through debugging of some sort? I do have xdebug configured.

I did debug through the code to the spot where I got an `undefined index` notice and I saw that the variable is set I just used the wrong name, but there are so many (unknown) spots where I would have to change it. I'm guessing finding out where it is set, and change it there would be quicker.

Comment: no extra files used? include 'filename';

or

require 'filename'; maybe the var is created there

Comment: the find function from phpstorm searches all files in the project :/

Comment: Wherever you're calling `someclass->getVar()` you can hold cmd and click the code and it should take you to where the initial code was formed.

Comment: I would step through your code using debugger. Session is a superglobal variable and can be set anywhere in the code. If the `some_index` is a static name I would try a full text search for index only, as it may be defined in session via variable.

Comment: @LukasHajdu Yeah I just tried that and 1 step after the line `session_start();` the index is already set and filled with the values that I wanted to know where they're coming from, can this be correct?

Comment: @Option yeah tried that too, but figured out that line of code never gets called :/

Comment: @LukasHajdu sorry for my stupidity, of course a session was already set when I was debugging.. started a new session and am debugging now, let's see how long it will take to find the right code