# What is the best way to find where a variable loaded in the memory is initially declared in a wordpress / laravel project?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

while trying my hand on wordpress, I can see there are so many functions loaded in the application's memory.

Is there a way to determine from where the variable gets loaded into memory?

Comment: How to find [function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222142/how-to-find-out-where-a-function-is-defined)

Comment: How to find [variable definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970806/find-where-a-variable-is-defined-in-php-and-or-smarty)